# How to pass a parameterized renderer function in Countdown component in React Countdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am using [react-countdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countdown). Is there any way to pass a parameterized callback function to the renderer prop in `Countdown` component (code below)?

This is the `Countdown` component I am using from react-countdown:

```
 <Countdown date={Date.now() + ms} renderer={rendererProp}/>
```

This is the `rendererProp` function definition.

```
const rendererProp = ({ days, hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) => {
    if (completed) {
        return <Completionist />;
    } else {
        return <div>
            <h3 ><strong>{days}d:{hours}h:{minutes}m:{seconds}s</strong></h3>
            <div onClick={() => window.location.href = "some_route"}>Time left</div>
        </div>;
    }
};
```

here the "some_route" has to be passed as a prop to the rendererProp callback function, is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass additional props to the rendererProp function by using the props parameter. You can modify the rendererProp function to accept an additional prop, such as route, and use it in the onClick handler

```
const rendererProp = ({ days, hours, minutes, seconds, completed }, props) => {
    if (completed) {
        return <Completionist />;
    } else {
        return <div>
            <h3 ><strong>{days}d:{hours}h:{minutes}m:{seconds}s</strong></h3>
            <div onClick={()=> window.location.href = props.route }>Time left</div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Then you can pass the route prop to the rendererProp function when rendering the Countdown component

```
<Countdown date={Date.now() + ms} renderer={(props) => rendererProp(props, { route: "/some_route" })}/>
```